# MYSQL UPDATE ...trying

Tags: mysql

Update data with MYSQL UPDATE
But I press a button EX: the light is ON
The first update is right
But after...trying... it will become OFF

Sorry, my English is not good. I don’t know if I can express what I mean.

```
...trying...
Connected to server version 5.5.5-10.4.20-MariaDB
UPDATE before outputfanState=on
outputwaterState=off
outputlightState=on
UPDATE pmth.control SET fan ='on', water='off',light='on' WHERE 1
Disconnected.
UPDATE after outputfanState=on
outputwaterState=off
outputlightState=on
New Client.
Client disconnected.

...trying...
Connected to server version 5.5.5-10.4.20-MariaDB
UPDATE before outputfanState=on
outputwaterState=off
outputlightState=on
UPDATE pmth.control SET fan ='on', water='off',light='on' WHERE 1
Disconnected.
UPDATE after outputfanState=on
outputwaterState=off
outputlightState=on
```

Comment: i have no clue whats going on there

Comment: try writing your question in your own language and then use a Translator to convert it to English, currently I dont think anyone will understand your question